# NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 131:

Tags: laravel

I know this is probably something really stupid but I just can't seem to fix it.

I'm getting this error

> NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 131: No query results for model [App\Modules\Menus\Models\Menu].

And can't seem to fix it. At the moment it shouldn't even be asking for the Menu model.

Here is my route.php

```
Route::get('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@signup',
    'as' => 'signup'
]);
```

Here is my OpenController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Open\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Modules\Menus\Models\Menu;
use App\Modules\Authors\Models\Story;

class OpenController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $menus_child = Menu::where('menu_id', 0)->with('menusP')->get();
        $menu = Menu::where('id', 1)->orWhere('title', 'home')->firstOrFail();
        return view('open::index', compact('menus_child', 'menu'));
    }

    public function content($id){
        $menus_child = Menu::where('menu_id', 0)->with('menusP')->get();
        $menu = Menu::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        $layout = $menu->type;
        $stories = Story::where('type', 'public')->get();

        return view('open::public/'.$layout, compact('menus_child', 'menu', 'stories'));
    }

    public function signup(){
        echo "sign up";
        die();
    }
}
```

Here is my signup.blade.php

```
@extends('templates::layouts.public')
@section('content')
    <h1>signup blade</h1>
@stop
```

Here is my public.blade.php layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cherry+Swash|Crafty+Girls|Homemade+Apple|Italianno|Parisienne|Ranga|Rochester" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
        {!! Html::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}
        {!! Html::style('css/style.css') !!}
        {!! Html::script('js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') !!}
        {!! Html::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') !!}
        {!! Html::script('js/main.js') !!}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="main">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="logo">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <h1>Website</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="slogan">
                                    {!! Html::link('/signup', 'Signup') !!} / {!! Html::link('/login', 'Login') !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @include('menus::menu')
                </div>
                <div id="site_content">
                    <div id="content">
                        @yield('content')
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my menu.blade.php

```
<div id="menubar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
        @foreach($menus_child as $grandfather)
            @if($grandfather->menu_id)
                <li>
            @elseif($grandfather->title == 'Home')
                <li class="parent {{ menu_active([$grandfather->id]) }}">
            @elseif(count($grandfather->menusP()->where('menu_id', '>', 0)->get()))
                <li class="dropdown {{ menu_active([$grandfather->id]) }}">
            @else
                <li class="parent {{ menu_active([$grandfather->id]) }}">
            @endif

            @if(count($grandfather->menusP()->where('menu_id', '>', 0)->get()))
                {!! HTML::decode(HTML::link($grandfather->id, $grandfather->title.'<span class="caret"></span>', array('class' => 'dropdown-toggle')))!!}
            @else
                {!! HTML::link($grandfather->id, $grandfather->title) !!}
            @endif

            @if(count($grandfather->menusP))
                <ul class="dropdown_menu">
                    @foreach($grandfather->menusP as $father)
                        @if($father->menu_id)
                            <li class="parent_child">
                        @else
                            <li>
                        @endif

                        {!! HTML::link($father->id, $father->title) !!}
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out what caused the issue. It was how I had my routes placed. So all I did was put my signup route on top of my routes and that solved my problem

Comment: @Gus - I'm not sure. I was just messing around, but if you do find out why I would appreciate it if you would let me know, because I'm confused as to why it happened

Answer (score 0):

@Gus, @Isis

This post helped me solve a very similar (or possibly same) issue.  In my particular case, I immediately realized it was simple user error - and this may help explain why this may happen...

Consider visiting the following URL given the subsequent routes:

**GET** app.com/team/add-favorite

[bad] **Routes:**

```
// Bad Routing Logic
Route::get('/team/{team}', 'TeamController@show');
Route::get('/team/add-favorite', 'UserTeamController@default');
Route::get('/team/add-favorite/{conference}', 'UserTeamController@index');
```

Obviously, the 2nd route ( /team/add-favorite ) will never be called because it's simply going to route to **/team/{team}** with the [team] parameter filled with a value of "add-favorite".

My solution was to also simply re-arrange the order of the routes, like so...

[better] **Routes:**

```
// Still not good practice, but works
Route::get('/team/add-favorite', 'UserTeamController@default');
Route::get('/team/add-favorite/{conference}', 'UserTeamController@index');
Route::get('/team/{team}', 'TeamController@show');
```

This is still definitely not best practice, but will at least allow each of the routes to resolve properly.

**app.com/team/add-favorite** will now match the first route, while something like **app.com/team/17** will still fall to the 3rd listed route and be handed to the TeamController with an appropriate ID.

Again - I don't recommend routing this way with "shared" endpoints as it could definitely still cause problems.  i.e - better hope there were never a team with and ID = 'add-favorite'.  Highly improbable, but you get the point...

Hope this helps!